# Asyncio run one function continuously and execute another function periodically

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have one function which is a websocket connection to some trading data which I want to run continuously, then every 5 minutes I want to run another function to scrape data from a website without interrupting the websocket.

I have the two functions working I'm just unsure if having the await asyncio.sleep(1) in the websocket is a good idea - surely it would slow down the function? I haven't been able to find another questions on here which show a different solution to what I'm currently doing.

Any suggestions/tips/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

```
async def websock():
    ubwa = unicorn_binance_websocket_api.BinanceWebSocketApiManager(exchange="binance.com")
    output = ubwa.create_stream(['trade', 'depth'], ['bnbusdt', 'bnbusd'], output='UnicornFy')
    while True:
        oldest_data_from_stream_buffer = ubwa.pop_stream_data_from_stream_buffer()
        if oldest_data_from_stream_buffer:
            print(oldest_data_from_stream_buffer)
            bnb_trade = oldest_data_from_stream_buffer['event_type'] = 'trade'
            markdepth = oldest_data_from_stream_buffer['event_type'] = 'depth_Update'
            await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def get_website_data():
    while True:
        try:
            #scrape data from website every 5 minutes
            await asyncio.sleep(300)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(websock())
loop.create_task(get_website_data())
loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: The `asyncio.sleep` is fine, it only suspends that coroutine. Others will continue to run.

Comment: Thanks Keith - so if I stored data into a database in the function there's no potential for the asyncio.sleep to cause the database to miss any data from the websocket?

Comment: It should not, as long as the rest of the function doesn't block.